# Insert webProperty with Java's "Google APIs Client Library"

Tags: java, groovy, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create a webProperty using the Java client but without success **(i have access to the beta testing group that allows the creation of webProperties)**. This is my code (it is actually a groovy class):

```
package com.creditpal.services


import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperty
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import uk.co.futureroute.lib.logging.annotation.MethodLogging


@Service
@MethodLogging
class GoogleAnalyticsServiceImpl implements GoogleAnalyticsService {


    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "##THE NAME##"


    private static final String EMAIL_ADDRESS = "##THE EMAIL ADDRESS##"


    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleAnalyticsServiceImpl.class)


    private JsonFactory jsonFactory


    private HttpTransport httpTransport


    private Analytics analytics


    public GoogleAnalyticsServiceImpl(){
        httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
        jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
        initializeAnalytics()
    }




    @Override
    public Webproperty insertWebProperty(String name, String websiteUrl) throws GoogleJsonResponseException {
        Webproperty webProperty = new Webproperty(
                websiteUrl: websiteUrl,
                name: name
        )


        try {
            return analytics.management().webproperties().insert("##ACCOUNT_ID##", webProperty).execute()
        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            logger.error("There was a google Analytics service error: "
                    + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                    + e.getDetails().getMessage());
            throw e
        }
    }


    private void initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
        analytics = new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, authorize()).setApplicationName(
                APPLICATION_NAME).build();
    }


    private Credential authorize() throws Exception {
        final File googlePrivateKey = File.createTempFile("googlePrivateKey", ".p12")
        googlePrivateKey.deleteOnExit()
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(this.class.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("resources/analytics.p12"), googlePrivateKey)


        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setServiceAccountId(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(googlePrivateKey)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_MANAGE_USERS))
                .build()
    }
}
```

This is a Spring service and when this object is created i dont get any exceptions. The problem is when trying to call the insertWebProperty method, there i get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature.signUsingRsaSha256(JsonWebSignature.java:498) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:378) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) ~[google-http-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460) ~[google-api-client-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
 at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$execute.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Anyone any idea?? Thanks in advance!